# can jenkins machine communicate with docker in pipeline script?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to docker, so I want to use it in my pipeline, in stage "build docker", which loads a docker machine, and in the second stage, I want to be using the jenkins machine, and try to communicate with the docker machine, is that possible? or with docker there is a different approach?
note that I used before to create an environment in stage one, which is implemented on a linux machine that be pinged from the jenkins machine.

Comment: The Jenkins documentation has a page on [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) which covers many common use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `agent` for using a docker image specifically for a stage. If you also set `reuseNode true` , once this stage is finished, pipeline will be executed with the initial docker.

```
stage("Any Stage") {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'YOUR_IMAGE'
            reuseNode true                  
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                //TODO
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: okay, but can I create after this "Any Stage", another stage which includes a code that runs on jenkins machine, and this code tries to communicate with the docker machine, is that feasible? @kaan-bobac

Comment: with the above way, docker container will be stopped afrer stage finishes. If you want to create a docker image working for several stages, I suggest creating docker image within node